# Dynamically add event CheckedChanged to checkBox in back page C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a custom CheckBox (CheckBoxColumn )

```
class CheckBoxColumn : ITemplate
{
    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;

    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = "IDCheckBox";
        cb.AutoPostBack= true;
        container.Controls.Add(cb);
    }

    protected void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.CheckedChanged != null)
            this.CheckedChanged(this, e); 
    }
}
```

so I can introduce the custom checkbox in a TemplateField

```
            CheckBoxColumn cb = new CheckBoxColumn();
            cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(ExecutarCheckBox_CheckedChanged);

            TemplateField checkBox = new TemplateField();
            checkBox.ItemTemplate = cb;
            gridviewexample.Columns.Add(checkBox);
```

But the event OnCheckedChanged is never reached.
When I click on the checkBox the page is reload and the column with the checkBox disappears.
Does any one know how can I get it to work?

//Code

```
namespace Namespace1
{
    public partial class ClasseName: SuperClass
    {

        private void AddColumnsToGridView(DataTable dt)
        {

            CheckBoxColumn cb = new CheckBoxColumn();
            cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(ExecutarCheckBox_CheckedChanged);

            TemplateField checkBox = new TemplateField();
            checkBox.ItemTemplate = cb;
            gridviewexample.Columns.Add(checkBox);

        }

    ...

        protected void ExecutarCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //code
        }

    }


    class CheckBoxColumn : ITemplate
    {
       public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;

       public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
       {
           CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
           cb.ID = "IDCheckBox";
           cb.AutoPostBack= true;
           container.Controls.Add(cb);
        }

        protected void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.CheckedChanged != null)
                this.CheckedChanged(this, e); 
        }
    }

}
```

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewexample" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="True" PagerType="DropDownList" PageSize="40" ShowFooter="true"

DataKeyNames="field1, field2, field3"

OnRowEditing="gridviewexample_RowEditing"
OnRowUpdating="gridviewexample_RowUpdating" 
OnPageIndexChanged="gridView_PageIndexChanged"
OnRowCancelingEdit="gridviewexample_RowCancelingEdit" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" 
OnRowDataBound="gridviewexample_RowDataBound"
OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging">                                    
<Columns>

       <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="Select" 
       ImageUrl="/images/edit.gif" >
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
        </asp:ButtonField>                                        
        <asp:BoundField DataField="field1" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="field1" Visible="true" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" FooterStyle-CssClass= "Hide" />                        
        <asp:BoundField DataField="field2" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="field2"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="field3" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="field3" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" FooterStyle-CssClass= "Hide" />                                     
</Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <span class="errorMsg" runat="server" id="lblNoRecords" visible='<%#(MadeSearch != null && MadeSearch.Value)?true:false%>'>
            </span>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: The method that was suppose to be trigger once i clicked on the checkbox is define in the back page when i create "cb".

protected void ExecutarCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       //code
}

I am not assigning state ( checked or unchecked) to the chekBox "cb" in this case because it can be always uncheked when i populate the grid.

Did this answer your question?

Comment: You need a method called : ExecutarCheckBox_CheckedChanged()

Comment: you do not show all relevant code so how is one to assume that you actually have a method defined as ` protected void ExecutarCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: For legal reason i have to change the name of the objects in the code but the intent maintain.
I updated the question to show all the code that i think is relevant, if you think that i should show more let me now.

Comment: I am trying to create the custom checkBox in the back page because if i create it on the page like this


<asp:TemplateField >
       <itemtemplate >
              <asp:CheckBox id="ExecutarCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ExecutarCheckBox_CheckedChanged" 
                AutoPostBack="True" ></asp:CheckBox>
 </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateField> 



the templateField dessapear after 3 postback  (it is a problem of the framework).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to bind your event to the inner-checkbox's event.
I couldn't test, but I think this will at least lead you to the right way :

```cs
class CheckBoxColumn : ITemplate
{
    private CheckBox _checkbox;
    private event EventHandler checkedChanged;
    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (_checkbox != null)
            {
                checkedChanged += value;
                _checkbox.CheckedChanged += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            if (_checkbox != null)
            {
                checkedChanged -= value;
                _checkbox.CheckedChanged -= value;
            }
        }
    }

    public CheckBoxColumn()
    {
        _checkbox = new CheckBox();
        _checkbox.ID = "IDCheckBox";
        _checkbox.AutoPostBack = true;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        if (_checkbox != null) container.Controls.Add(_checkbox);
    }

    protected void OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = checkedChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}
```